# Is 1GB of RAM with 500GB of hard disk and dual core processor is sufficient to run Windows 7 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7

Is 1GB of RAM with 500GB of hard disk and dual core processor 2.7Gh is sufficient to run Windows 7 Ultimate?

Comment: In my opinion, 1G of RAM is not enough for adequate performance on W7, unless you have a somehow limited application suite.

Comment: Shouldn't we also know the video card?

Comment: Ultimate will be dog slow on 1gb ram, 2gb is minimum, 3 and up is better.

Comment: Also depends if it is a 32-bit or a 64-bit installation. It will run okay, as others have said, but as soon as you start running much by way of programs, services, and background processes, you'll have issues.

Answer (score 3):

It'll install and run okay.  May be a bit slow at times if many apps are ran simultaneously but certainly useable.  Consider putting 2GB of RAM in there at your earliest opportunity.